# tikz node align text to bottom of rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I align the text of a node to the bottom of the rectangle shape without hard coding values? (centered horizontally but justified to the bottom)

```
\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=8pt, minimum height=1.2cm, fill=black, text=white, font=\huge, text depth=-0.6cm] {test};
}\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=8pt, minimum height=1.2cm, fill=black, text=white, font=\huge, text depth=0cm] {test};
}\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=8pt, minimum height=1.2cm, fill=black, text=white, text depth=-0.6cm] {test};
}\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=8pt, minimum height=1.2cm, fill=black, text=white, text depth=0cm] {test};
}
```

Obviously `text depth` can be hard coded but I would like it to automatically work for any given font and rectangle height.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What alignment do you want with letters like 'y' and 'A'?

Comment: also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140496/align-text-to-top-left-in-a-tikz-block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the text size is smaller than the minimum height you could try to use `text height` instead of `minimum height`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=0pt, fill=black, text=white, 
         font=\huge, text height=1.2cm] {test};
}

\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=0pt, fill=black, text=white, 
         font=\huge, text height=1.2cm] {test yjp};
}

\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=0pt, fill=black, text=white, 
        font=\huge, text height=1.2cm,text depth=0cm] {test yjp};
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Possible :  `\parbox` this macro takes an optional argument to set the height of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz \node[shape          = rectangle, 
            inner sep      = 0pt, draw,
            fill           = black,
            text           = white, 
            minimum height = 2cm,
            minimum width  = 4cm] {\parbox[b][2cm]{4cm}{Simple \huge{test}}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create a vertical box of a given height and put your text at the bottom of that box. This can be done with the following macro:

```
\def\bottom#1#2{\hbox{\vbox to #1{\vfill\hbox{#2}}}}
```

You can use the above macro inside a TikZ node. The "bad" part is that you have to give the desired height of that box, and that you have to take into account the `inner sep` (which would be added to the given height), and the `minimum height` (which has to be greater or equal, preferibly equal, to the sum of the given height plus the two inner seps).

The following MWE will make more clear what I mean, I hope:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\bottom#1#2{\hbox{\vbox to #1{\vfill\hbox{#2}}}}

\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=1mm, minimum height=1.2cm, fill=black, text=white, font=\huge] {test};
}\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=1mm, minimum height=1.2cm, fill=black, text=white, font=\huge] {\bottom{1cm}{test}};
}\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=1mm, minimum height=1.2cm, fill=black, text=white] {test};
}\tikz[]{
        \node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=1mm, minimum height=1.2cm, fill=black, text=white] {\bottom{1cm}{test}};
}
\end{document}
```

With the following result:

[image: Output]

Comment: yes, but my goal is to avoid having to manually calculate things. Else I can just set text depth directly. In both cases if something changes I'll have to manually change all the values. In your case though there is a lot more overhead.