# Align text to top left in a TikZ block

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have a TikZ block defined. The text inside it is not getting vertically aligned to the top. The following is the code I am using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 6cm, auto]
  \node [block, right of=interface] (conn) {
  \small ConnectedTo
  \linebreak
  \tiny
  \setlength{\leftmargini}{1.5em}
  \vspace{-4    mm}
  \begin{itemize}
    \itemsep0em
    \item Status: Up
  \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The resulting image is:

[image: Block 1]

Is there a way to align the text "top-left"?

Comment: It may be easier to do the things in: [Vertical space inside a TikZ node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139719)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put your text in a separate node and place it correspondingly

```
\node[below right] at (conn.north west) {Your text};
```